# Receive input from a physical key without a textbox (Like a hotkey)

Tags: java, hotkeys

I am trying to make a program that outputs some data when I press a physical key on my keyboard.  Is there anyway to do this without having either the cmd selected or a gui?
Thanks, Not sure how clear this sounds, but if you need clarification ask and I'll try again

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064296/check-whether-shift-key-is-pressed) (focus on the code in the question, not the answer) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160315/how-to-check-for-key-being-held-down-on-startup-in-java) may be a starting point.

Comment: The question is not clear...
what is your GUI.... where you want input the keys...
What is the application from which user is interacting with your app...